# Using ShouldChangeCharacters breaks mvvmcross databinding

Tags: ios, data-binding, mvvmcross

I subclassed a UITextField for phone number input and I added a delegate for ShouldChangeCharacters to make sure that the input was in the ddd-ddd-dddd format. I auto insert the dashes and handle the backspace to include the dash.

I modify the field text directly and always return false from the delegate.

```
        this.ShouldChangeCharacters = (field, range, replacementString) =>
        {
            int oldLength = field.Text.Length;
            int replacementLength = replacementString.Length;
            int rangeLength = range.Length;
            int newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;
            if (newLength <= 12)
            {
                if (replacementLength == 0)
                {
                    if (field.Text.EndsWith("-"))
                        field.Text = field.Text.Substring(0, field.Text.Length - 2);
                    else
                        field.Text = field.Text.Substring(0, field.Text.Length - 1);

                }
                else
                {
                    int digit = 0;
                    if (int.TryParse(replacementString, out digit))
                    {
                        field.Text = field.Text + replacementString;
                        if (newLength == 3 || newLength == 7)
                            field.Text = field.Text + "-";
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
```

The issue that I am having is that this seems to bypass the mvvmcross databinding. In my binding set (in the view) I used:

```
set.Bind(textPhone).To(vm => vm.Phone);
```

The Phone property is not being set in my view model.

Is there anyway to make sure that the changes to the UITextField Text property are seen by databinding?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here (I think) is that returning `false` prevents the `EditingChanged` event from firing.

To work around this it's probably easiest to add a new UITextField control:

```
    public class MyField : UITextField
    {
        public MyField (RectangleF rect)
            : base(rect)
        {
            this.ShouldChangeCharacters = (f, r, r2) => {

                                    // your logic here
                this.Text += ".";

                                    var handler = CleanTextChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                return false;
            };                          
        }

        public event EventHandler CleanTextChanged;

        public string CleanText { 
            get { return Text; }
            set { Text = value; }
        }
    }
```

This can then be used in place of UITextField and can be bound using:

```
set.Bind(cleanTextPhone).For(v => v.CleanText).To(vm => vm.Phone);
```

If you want to use the smaller expression - without the `For` - then you'll need to add `CleanText` as the default binding property for a `MyField`

Answer (score 0):

A more simple approach is doing the following after setting the text

```
myTextField.SendActionForControlEvents(UIControlEvent.EditingChanged);
```

Credit to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792058/5137291

Comment: UIControlEvent.EditingDidEnd

Comment: I don't get the reason for your comment. Is it an addition or a correction of your answer?

Comment: It was supposed to be a correction but it is incorrect. EditingChanged is the correct answer in this scenario.