# Manually setting "text" for a UITextField does not call .EditingChanged

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have subclassed UITextField which has the target

```
self.addTarget(self, action: "onChange:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

This works fine when the user is typing in the textfield. Although I would need to the same method "onChange:" to be called when the textfield's "text" property is manually updated.

```
let tf = CustomTextField()
tf.text = "Trigger !!!"
```

How could I do this ?

Comment: If my answer has solved your issue, please mark as it so.

Answer (score 18):

This is intentional, to prevent endless echo if you need to change the text programmatically in an event handler.

Use `sendActions(for controlEvents:)` to manually notify event handlers.

```
tf.text = "Trigger !!!"
tf.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
```